# Server reboots at booting linux based softwares

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

We have a dl380p gen8 hp server and it was just working fine till one reboot that we don't know what happened but as a result our ESXi os does not boot anymore, it just goes to reboot after loading files and the step when esx is initiating first things like scheduler and users..
Ubuntu installer disk does also reboot before showing installation options, just the purple screen and then it goes down

also I was able to catch an error while booting the ubuntu installer and that was "hw pmu has corrupted firmware" and as I googled folk has said that disabling "Processor Power and Utilization Monitoring" would help as below link will explain, but still I'm  stuck in that reboot loop thing but ubuntu prints no other error just plain reset occurs
please help

http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03265132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of headache I finally decided to check every single piece of hardware on the aforementioned device and turned out that one of the RAMs was out of function but the device did not gave proper error in that regard

Answer (score 0):

How to disable “Processor Power and Utilization Monitoring”:

– enter BIOS (press F9 during boot)

– press CTRL+A (Service Option is hidden by default)

– select “Service Options” -> Processor Power and Utilization Monitoring -> Disable

Press F10 to save and exit and reboot the server.

Comment: I already did that based on the link I provided dear and I explained after that I don't get no errors but the system reboots around same time anyway

Comment: Then i suggest you use HP diagnostics tools and test your system. I suspect hardware failure.

Comment: thanks dear
but already did that, the system does not show any failures, all tests pass...
we've send it to vendor for now